# Couldn't connect MIDI controller on Ardour (Ubuntu 18.04 Ardour5)

Tags: sound, alsa, jack

I was followin the instrucions to setup Cadence (http://bcacciaaudio.com/2018/01/30/audio-music-production-in-linux-part-1-setting-up-jack-audio/) from this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vh5Z5qmUcew).

The problem is that I can't see the MIDI controller In Ardour5, when I go to Window < MIDI 
Neither in QjackCtrl on the menu Conections < MIDI can't find it either (Here i don't see the ALSA tab since I run `a2jmidid -e` after starting Jack)

This is my hardware

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [PCH ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH 
HDA Intel PCH at 0xc0610000 irq 28 
1 [O61 ]: USB-Audio - Oxygen 61 
M-Audio Oxygen 61 at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, full speed
```

On CL comments:

```
$ amidi -l
Dir Device    Name
IO  hw:1,0,0  Oxygen 61 MIDI 1
$ arecordmidi -l
 Port    Client name                      Port name
 14:0    Midi Through                     Midi Through Port-0
 20:0    Oxygen 61                        Oxygen 61 MIDI 1
```

Seems it's not Firmware problem...

[Cadence/Jack Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYhve.jpg)

I'm not sure about the Imput and Output device nor the MIDI Device values that I choose.

Comment: As far as I know, older Oxygen keyboards need a separate [firmware loader](https://github.com/oeai/m-audio-usb-midi-fw).

Comment: I was able to conect it at some point, I can conect the MIDI controller on LMMS and the sound comes out, but not in Ardour. I don't know if this would be possible if there were a problem with firmware...

Comment: Does it show up in the output of `amidi -l`, and `arecordmidi -l`? (Neither would be possible with missing firmware.)

Comment: Well as you can see I'm New in Ubuntu, Before I was using FLSTUDIO, what I need is just some good Piano (I was used to the sound of Nexus 2, seem good enough) and Synths.
I just bought a XLR to USB to record with a mic... which neither I know how to link to Ardour :( Thank you for the help!